# Google maps are loaded in Earth view

Tags: android, google-maps, google-earth

I am displaying google maps in my android application. 
However, I am able to see the maps in [earth/satellite](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.3360008,-121.8847221,2811m/data=!3m1!1e3) mode. 
I want to see them in [normal](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.3360008,-121.8847221,15z) mode.

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: How are your getting/using your map? Can you show the map related code?

Comment: @antonio, The second function in the above edit is used to display marker on current location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map) you just need to call `mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);` on a valid `GoogleMap` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't see the code for your map, I'm only assuming that you have it and by default have it set to Satellite view. 

You can alter the map styles by setting it explicitly:

```
GoogleMap newMap;
//Your map code here    
newMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

You can find more information at [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#change_the_map_type)